# Altbeacon Scan on Command

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, altbeacon

I am using AltBeacon for Bluetooth iBeacon detection on an Android device (android-beacon-library). Currently, the only way I am able to pick up beacons is via a callback: `RangeNotifier`.

However, the functionality I desire is every 5 seconds, perform a scan for nearby beacons, and only do so 10 times total (i.e. scan for around a minute). I would like to be able to scan in a for loop, but it seems like the only way to do it so far is with the callback and I cannot control when it is fired.

Does anyone know if this behavior is possible using the Android AltBeacon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is not designed for this kind of ad-hoc scanning, but it is possible to do what you'd like with the following technique:

1. Set the scan period to be five seconds with:

   ```
   mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000l);
   ```
2. Set a start timestamp when you start ranging:

   ```
   mScanStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
   ```
3. The scan callback will get called once every five seconds with a list of beacons detected.  Process these beacons, and stop scanning if 50 seconds (10 scans) has passed:

   ```
   @Override
   public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
     // Process beacons here
     if (System.currentTimeMillis() - mScanStartTime > 50*1000l) {
       mBeaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Awesome, I was hoping I could trigger them on command but this solution will work great. Thanks @davidgyoung